# Log of heat equation: Name for the PDE $\phi_t=\phi_{xx}+\phi_x^2$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation, parabolic-pde, nonlinear-dynamics

Suppose $u(x,t)$ satisfies the heat equation $u_t=u_{xx}.$ Assume $u(x,0) > 0$ for all $x$; then, by the maximum principle, $u(x,t)>0$ for all $x,t$.

Define $\phi(x,t):=\log u(x,t)$.  Then, by a simple calculation, $\phi(x,t)$ satisfies the PDE $$\phi_t=\phi_{xx}+\phi_x^2.$$  **Does this nonlinear PDE have a name?  Or, does it belong to a larger class of PDEs that people study?**  Any relevant search terms would be helpful.

Comment: I am not aware of any specific names for this equation. More generally though, it is an example of a semilinear heat equation: $\phi_t- \phi_{xx}=f(u_x)$. It's also a supersolution of the heat equation: $\phi_t-\phi_{xx}\geqslant 0$.

Comment: I also think it looks similar to the evolution porous medium equation with $p=2$: $\phi_t=\frac12(\phi^2)_{xx}$ since $(\phi^2)_{xx} = 2\phi_x^2+2\phi\phi_{xx}$. However, this is unlikely to be of much help in my opinion

Comment: Thanks @JackT!  This appears to be an easy case of the semilinear heat equation, where we know solutions won't blow up since they're related to solutions of the classical heat equation.  I'm surprised it doesn't seem to have a well-known name, since it's such a simple PDE!